# Jquery cycle plugin float problem and browser compatibility

Tags: jquery-plugins, google-chrome, cross-browser, cycle-plugin

I'm building a new site for myself as freelancer. I'm planning to use the cycle plugin in the header but I'm experiencing a small problem.
I wrote HTML and CSS for de items that need to be cycled. Each div.feature inside div#featured should be cycled. A div.feature exist of an image and a div.info. They are both floated left, so they would appear next to eachother.
After writing the HTML and CSS I wrote the Jquery and when I test the page I see the first div.feature perfectly displayed, but after the first cycle all the floats seem to go wrong.

You can check it here: http://webstudions.be/projects/layout6/

Also chrome and safari seem the make another mistake as firefox, ie9 and opera.

Does anybody has an idea of how I should fix this or how I could get this to work??

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS Try adding the following line to your elements style:

```
clear: both;
```

This generally fixes my float problems.